# How can I play the sound from the audio in through my speakers?

Tags: mac, audio, speakers

I have got a Macbook Pro 15" that has both an audio in and out port. Now I would like to play the sound from an external device through the speakers of my Mac.

How can I do that? I tried to just plug in the 3.5mm cable from my external device into the audio in port but I simply cannot make my Mac play the sound. However, in System Preferences -> Sound -> Input I can see that the Mac is receiving the signals.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have Garageband installed you can also use Quicktime.

1. Open Quicktime
2. Go to `File -> New Audio Recording`. You will see the following screen:
   [image]
3. Click on the little triangle on the right and choose `Built-in Input: Line in` as shown in the screenshot.
4. Slide the volume under the record button up until you have the desired loudness.

Comment: For me this imposes about 300ms input delay. Is there a way to adjust that delay (perhaps by means of some ´defaults´ setting for QuickTime)?

Comment: Don't think you can configure QuickTime, it sounds like a latency problem What device are you connecting?

Comment: the delay is bad

Comment: I can confirm this adds a significant delay. The on-screen meter responds to sounds almost immediately, but I don't hear them until several hundred ms later. The latency seems to be added by Quicktime.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GarageBand:

1. Create a new project and choose for example the voice template
2. Set Monitor to On

   [image]
3. Optionally remove the effects from the Edit tab

Comment: I also found delay using this method :(

Comment: Any tips on preventing feedback when used for Karaoke?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SoundSource app from Rogue Amoeba to set your sound on "Play-Thru". Or you can do it in their free Line-In app, which has been retired but can still be downloaded.

Comment: The free app: *LineIn* worked for me, up until I upgraded OSX to 10.14 mojave- now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party but I’ve stumbled on a solution on another StackOverflow website that led me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jib1/7ejwaxkc

It works wonderfully as an audio passthrough. Took me ages to find... phew!

Enjoy!

EDIT: Found out the solution isn’t perfect: it’s mono. :(

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @grg Ah yes, good point. Thanks! (I’m a total newb, as you may have found, haha... )