# Getting game console LineIn audio in Macbook Air M1 2020

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

I'd like to get audio out of the USB(A) ports on the Nintendo Switch and PS5(Only one at a time) into the Macbook Air M1 2020. This because I would like to chat with friends using Discord while also getting game audio in my earbuds.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Right now I have a little sound card with an male USB(A) on one side and a female 3.5mm on the other, this manage to get sound out of the consoles but then when testing with my Macbook and an aux cable, I discovered the 3.5mm port is output only so I didn't manage to get the audio in.

PS5 has a good chat functionality for getting both chat and game audio but I have friends with whom I crossplay that only have Discord. Also, since there is no good chat app in Nintendo Switch(they only have it for a few games via a smartphone app), having both Discord and the Switch game audio would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered many times before here at Ask Different. The best I can do is post this answer and give links to other answers.

### Updated Answer

In your comments, you referenced the inability to hear the sound from the MacBook air. This problem has also been addressed by the question "[How can I play the sound from the audio in through my speakers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112053/how-can-i-play-the-sound-from-the-audio-in-through-my-speakers)". Evidently, there was a noticeable delay when using many (if not all) of the solutions posted in the answers. This updated answer attempts to avoid digitally mixing the two audio signals.

I assume you already have analog line level output from both the Nintendo Switch and PS5. The devices mentioned in my original answer can provide analog line level output from the Mac. *However, I believe the headphone output on your Mac could be substituted for an analog line level output, if the output level was set low enough.* Below is an example of a powered headphone amplifier which can combine analog line level inputs and provide output to your earbuds.

[Donner DEL-8i2 4-Channel Stereo Line Headphone Mixer](https://www.donnerdeal.com/products/donner-del-8i2-4-channel-stereo-line-headphone-mixer-mini-audio-mixer-with-floating-grounding-ideal-for-club-or-bar-mixer-for-microphones-guitars-bass-keyboards-or-stage-sub-mixer-n5?currency=USD&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping&utm_campaign=gs-2020-11-19&utm_source=google&utm_medium=smart_campaign&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgLjCgcuA9AIVFa_ICh35agzFEAQYAiABEgJSz_D_BwE)

[image]

[image]

### My Original Answer

You need to purchase a device that has line in ports and can plug into one of your Mac's existing USB-C ports. Many of the previous answers have referred to Behringer's line of [USB audio interfaces](https://www.amazon.com/stores/page/7E3BDD45-747D-4EE8-A545-C0C5439677A5?ingress=2&visitId=c5cbb76c-52c2-4de7-961a-0ac625997a38&ref_=ast_bln). Three of the lower priced Mac compatible USB audio interfaces are given below. These are ordered by lowest list price first.

- [Behringer U-Phono UFO202 Audiophile USB/Audio Interface with Built-in Phono Preamp,Black](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002GHBYZ0)
  While this model will solve your problem, there is also a phonograph preamp, which you may have another use for.

  [image]
- [BEHRINGER A- B Box, 2 x RCA Phono (UCA202)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KW2YEI)
  While this model will solve your problem, there is also an optical digital output, which you may have another use for.

  [image]
- [Behringer U-Control UCA222 Ultra-Low Latency 2 In/2 Out USB Audio Interface with Digital Output](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0023BYDHK)
  While this model will solve your problem, there is also an optical digital output and additional software, which you may have another use for.

  [image]

To use one of the above device, you will need the following:

- An adaptor to go from the device's USB-A jack to your Mac's USB-C port.
- An adaptor to go from the female 3.5mm port to the device's two RCA line in ports.

### UCA202 Versus UCA222

The comparison below was taken from the article "[Behringer UCA202 vs UCA222](https://recordingbro.com/behringer-uca202-vs-uca222/)" by admin; published July 4, 2019 at [Recordingbro.com](https://recordingbro.com).

> *"Physically, both of them are identical models with the latter being a newer model but, there is something that sets them apart and probably what most important when considering these interface. As an older model, UCA202 comes with a free and open source Audacity as well as Kreative’s Kristal Audio Engine. On the other hand, Behringer UCA222 is packed with those two but also added with EnergyXT2.5 or the Compact Behringer Edition as well as another disk with more than 100 virtual instruments and 50+ plug-ins."*

### Links

- This question is for a different Mac, but problem is the same: [How to accept USB as audio input for New Macbook Pro Retina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223980/how-to-accept-usb-as-audio-input-for-new-macbook-pro-retina) (asked Jan 18 `16)
- This question is also for a different Mac, but problem is the same: [I can't find LINE IN - Audio Input Problem with a Mac Book pro early 2015](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405979/i-cant-find-line-in-audio-input-problem-with-a-mac-book-pro-early-2015) (asked Nov 8 `20)
- This question is almost exactly the same: [MacBook Air 2020 Audio Line In](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415260/macbook-air-2020-audio-line-in) (asked Mar 8 `21) However, currently no answers are posted, but there are useful comments.

Comment: I just set up the devices as specified but still cant get the sound in the Macbook air. However I can hear the sound through the monitor output. Weird thing is I can see the input level rising while playing if I check the sound settings, but can't hear a thing. I have already tried setting the output to speakers and to my Airpods in the mac sound settings.

Comment: Managed to get some audio using monitoring with quick time but there is a noticeable delay. Is this normal?

Comment: I updated my answer. I suppose I should have given your question more thought before posting my original answer.

Comment: I like the mixer idea but then one question arises. So both the game console and mac are connected to the mixer with rca cables and the I connect my headset to the output of the mixer. Will I still be able to use my mic?

Comment: I do not have your model Mac or your earbuds. Can I assume your earbuds have a built‑in microphone and therefore a TRRS plug? Can I assume you have already confirmed the microphone works with your Mac through the headphone jack? –